# How to extract or parse particular line of text from notepad using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Below I have a Multitext in **notepad.txt**   File where I want to extract all the values of **external_uid column** only and print all the value in a list variable *external_value* using **python script**.

Can anybody help me with the script code? (I am a beginner in Python)

> For Example:

`external_value = ['0114e606-df6c-4657-8a57-ae104a541787', '0144d28b-95ac-4b06-8f24-678635a68f63', ......, '25b30794-ce69-4538-8675-bb568dac1296']` [image]

Comment: What have you tried? Why doesn't it work? Why have you tagged this with django?

Comment: I tried like placing this textfile in a for each loop but didnot know what to code actually.

Comment: I tagged with django because it might get solve with that too (May be as I am newbie to python django)

Comment: In which case please share your code and research, Stack Overflow is here to help you learn and solve specific problems, not just write coe for you. Django is a framework for web applications, it has nothing to do with parsing text files.

Comment: Ok I didnot knew much about django but that does not mean u will downvote my question @SimonN . I didnot share my code as I didnot know where to start. I already remarked in my question I am new to python and django

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```py
results = [] 
with open("notepad.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for id, external_uid, num, cst in line.split("|"):
            results.append(external_uid)
```

Comment: Its not working actually @Florian as beacuse it got stuck in the many irregular space near many value. Do you know how to cleansing this text file.

Comment: Update your question, like this I can't help you.